# bitcoin transaction is still unconfirmed after 30+ hours

Tags: blockchain.info, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, electrum, zero-confirmation

Yesterday evening (6.45pm) i moved 1.4 bitcoin from my local bitcoin wallet to my blockchain wallet, the transaction was completed. But before the transaction was fully complete i submitted a request that the coins be sent to my electrum wallet. the transaction to my electrum wallet is still unconfirmed, what are my options at this point? im fairly new to bitcoin and looking for any advice/help. thank you

https://blockchain.info/tx/21b904c02634330718c23285979cfed8ce2ba769cf9a7cd95bac1083c052099e

here is the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused the transaction has 22 confirmations (right now).

A good way to speed it up is to use a Bitcoin Accelerator